# Why does Python Regex complain with my substitution?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace a group of strings in a .csv file that have an extra "," comma and want to delete the extra comma. TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

```
import sys
import re

with open(sys.argv[1], "r", 500000000) as file_in:
    contents = file_in.readlines()

with open("output.csv", "w") as file_out:
    for line in contents:
        line = re.sub(r"tx->{[0-9a-fA-F]{3},",tx->{[0-9a-fA-F]{3}, line)
```

My data looks like this:

```
mps,tx->{67f, 40 34 30 00 00 00 00 00} rx<-{5f3, 4b 34 30 00 88 00 00 00},<S t='n' c='GELE' s='7'/>{Hea
```

Would like my data to look like:

```
mps,tx->{67f 40 34 30 00 00 00 00 00} rx<-{5f3, 4b 34 30 00 88 00 00 00},<S t='n' c='GELE' s='7'/>{Hea
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture what you want to keep in a capture group and then replace the match with that:

```
re.sub(r'(tx->{[0-9a-fA-F]{3}),', r'\1', line)
```

Alternatively, use a positive lookbehind to match the start of the string and then just replace the `,` with nothing:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=tx->{[0-9a-fA-F]{3}),', '', line)
```

If you also want to replace the `,` in the `rx` text, replace `tx->` in the regexes above with `(tx->|rx<-)`